# cannot compute moving average with bottleneck package- python

Tags: python

I'm using package `bottleneck` in order to compute a moving average of a np array.

My data is an array with shape (1247,1) , float, data between 0 and 1.

When I apply a simple

```
move_mean(my_array,12,min_count=1)
```

it gives me this error

```
moving window (=12) must between 1 and 1
```

Maybe an array-shape related problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
move_mean(my_array,12,min_count=1,axis=0)
```

You need to specify axis.